# What does my timestamp come from the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm displaying events from a PostgreSQL database, and my timestamps show as if they are going to happen in four hours..

Using `select * from event` in my database shows the correct timestamp. Why is rails displaying a different timestamp than what is in the database?

I would like to just show the timestamp as it is in the database.

Controller code:

```
ips_timestamp = event.timestamp.to_s(format = :db)

@ips_events += [timestamp: ips_timestamp]
```

View code:

```
<% @ips_events.each do |event| %>
<%= event[:timestamp] %>
```

Comment: You probably have a mix of `timestamp` and `timestamptz`. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170

Comment: I would also be willing to bet it has to do with timezones...

Comment: My timezone is default UTC. This is only changed in `application.rb` right?

Comment: Also check the timeline settings for postgresql

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, you where right. It was a `timestamptz` issue. Post as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a mix of the data types [`timestamp` and `timestamptz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html). Like saving a `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`), but later displaying a `timestamp without timezone` (`timestamp`) or vice versa.

Details in this related answer:
[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)